# Open Web Analytics tracking doesn't work

Tags: tracking, web-analytics

I am a new owa(Open Web Analytics) user, I have installed owa in /owa/apache/htdocs/owa
and create one index.html under /owa/apache/htdocs with blow content
However I won’t be able to see any analytic statistics from owa after I refreshed index.html several times

```
<html>
<header>
<!– Start Open Web Analytics Tracker –>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
//<![CDATA[
var owa_baseUrl = 'http://localhost/owa/';
var owa_cmds = owa_cmds || [];
owa_cmds.push(['setSiteId', '4f9312bd29c7edd4d492210b8599a383']);
owa_cmds.push(['trackPageView']);
owa_cmds.push(['trackClicks']);
owa_cmds.push(['trackDomStream']);

(function() {
var _owa = document.createElement(‘script’); _owa.type = ‘text/javascript’; _owa.async = true;
owa_baseUrl = (‘https:’ == document.location.protocol ? window.owa_baseSecUrl || owa_baseUrl.replace(/http:/, ‘https:’) : owa_baseUrl );
_owa.src = owa_baseUrl + ‘modules/base/js/owa.tracker-combined-min.js’;
var _owa_s = document.getElementsByTagName(‘script’)[0]; _owa_s.parentNode.insertBefore(_owa, _owa_s);
}());
//]]>
</script>
<!– End Open Web Analytics Code –>
</header>
<body>
<h1>It works!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you ca see here: https://github.com/Open-Web-Analytics/Open-Web-Analytics/wiki/Troubleshooting

> OWA uses cookies for tracking and for logging not the the admin interface. Therefor you must run OWA under a fully qualified domain (FQD) such as my.domain.com. Accessing and running OWA under http://localhost or an IP address will create errors.

Hoe this helps you :)

Answer (score -2):

There are a few issues with your HTML. For instance, you need to specify a doctype for your html tag. Also,  should be .

I've cleaned up your code, but haven't check to see if this works. Give this a shot though:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Blah</title>

<script>
//<![CDATA[
var owa_baseUrl = 'http://localhost/owa/';
var owa_cmds = owa_cmds || [];
owa_cmds.push(['setSiteId', '4f9312bd29c7edd4d492210b8599a383']);
owa_cmds.push(['trackPageView']);
owa_cmds.push(['trackClicks']);
owa_cmds.push(['trackDomStream']);

(function() {
var _owa = document.createElement('script'); _owa.type = 'text/javascript'; _owa.async = true;
owa_baseUrl = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? window.owa_baseSecUrl || owa_baseUrl.replace(/http:/, 'https:') : owa_baseUrl );
_owa.src = owa_baseUrl + 'modules/base/js/owa.tracker-combined-min.js';
var _owa_s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; _owa_s.parentNode.insertBefore(_owa, _owa_s);
}());
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>It works!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```